# How to configure in war type project of java to use Bytebuddy

Tags: java, configuration, pom.xml, byte-buddy

For a jar-type project which does have main-class I am using the below configuration.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>shade-my-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Main-Class>com.example.demo.SamplesJavaApplication</Main-Class>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

How to configure in war-type project, since i don't have main-class.

Comment: Not sure what your question is. The shade plugin has nothing to do with Byte Buddy.

Comment: I saw this configuration in some sample applications, Can you then tell me what should be the configuration in the application to use the Bytebuddy both in normal spring boot project and Java EE (war) type project.

Comment: and from the configuration i meant that, we can define main class in manifest file. but i am running my application using tomcat since it is a Java EE application with jsp, servlets which doesn't have main class.

Comment: Byte Buddy is a library and can be used as one. Are you trying to build a Java agent maybe?

Comment: yes i am using a custom java agent using bytebuddy in the premain

Comment: An agent needs to be bundled as a jar and attached to a jvm, either at startup or dynamically by pid.